# Create a multiple jpg from a pattern of png files

Tags: bash, imagemagick-convert

I wish to convert the last six png files (by date created) in a directory, convert them to jpg files and create from them a single multiple jpg file.

I've tried:`for i in $(ls -1t | head -6); do echo $i; convert $i +adjoin MULTI.JPG; done`

This does produce a multiple jpg, but it contains every png file in the directory, it not the last six. Which seems odd because echoing $i instead of converting it lists only the 6 wanted files.

I'd be grateful for assistance.

Comment: Can you describe what a *"single multiple JPEG file"* would look like please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the last 6 PNG images arranged side-by-side left-to-right, you can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

Nwanted=6
filenames=($(ls -t -- *.png 2>/dev/null| head -n $Nwanted))
if [ ${#filenames[*]} -eq $Nwanted ] ; then
   magick "${filenames[@]}" +append result.png
   exit 0
else
   >&2 echo "Insufficient PNG files present"
   exit 1
fi
```

---

If you want them aligned left-to-right across the page by their centres rather than by their top edges, use:

```
magick -gravity center ...
```

---

If you want them concatenated vertically above each other down the page instead of left-to-right across the page, use:

```
magick ... -append result.png
```

---

If you want them spaced 10 pixels apart left-to-right across the page, on a yellow background, use:

```
magick -background yellow ... +smush 10 result.png
```

---

If you want them laid out in a 3x2 grid, with 5 pixels spacing horizontally and vertically, on a cyan background, use:

```
magick montage -background cyan -tile 3x2 -geometry +5+5 "${filenames[@]}" result.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I think you are an array variable for the Nwanted png files. I'm not familiar and I'll need to work a bit on the syntax! But there's still a problem with the result. The command for Imagemagick 6 is apparently "convert", rather than magick. Code line

```convert "${filenames[@]}" +append result.png```

produces a png file the first page of which has the newest 6 images as a composite image, neatly in a horizontal line. But additional pages contained behind the first (when I open in EoG) containing ALL of the png files in the directory, in this case 11 files.

Comment: I can't understand it.

What I actually want to achieve is a multi-page graphics image (jpg or png) that contains the 6 newest image files, each on an individual page, so I can scroll through them. This is actually for a series of recent screenshots which I keep on screen.

Comment: Neither PNG nor JPEG support multi-page. You can use TIFF as the output format for multi-page, and drop the `-append` in that case.

Comment: If using v6 **ImageMagick**, just use `convert` in place of `magick`. And use `montage` in place of `magick montage`

Comment: You can add a line of debug on the line following `if` like this to see the filenames it has selected `printf '%s\n' "${filenames[@]}"`

Comment: Thanks again Mark. My mistake over jpg and png. Have just done a conversion to tiff and that will certainly do. Funny though, that result.png. Eye of Gnome shows the joined images plus every file in the directory. Though gimp opens only the jointed images. Don't understand.  But you've given me what I want, and many  thanks.